# How to verify aadhar card no using some API

Tags: aadhaar

in my company's project, I am building an verification mechanism where i need to validate my user via there aadhar card no.

Researched done so far
1) I can validate if an aadhar card no is of valid format(i have not tried it yet) by using Verhoeff Algorithm.

But i need to check whether this aadhar card belongs to the one who entered it as input on my website.

I learned about AadharAPI but i need to provide all my company details for using that api and it is paid  :-( . And documentation of using Aadhar Api is not so good(negligible).

Is there any rest api that can give me result in such a way that i hit on that api and i get the result whether that aadhar card no belongs to **This** person or not.

Comment: As I know, without calling UIDAI Aadhar API, we cannot check the Aadhar card details. We can only validate the user entered Aadhar number with the help of Verhoeff Algorithm. "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/aadhaarauth" this google group will help u.

Comment: To use aadhaar API, you need to contact companies which are Authentication Service Agency (ASA)/e-KYC Service Agency(KSA) or Authentication User Agency (AUA) /KYC User Agency (KUA) that uses Aadhaar authentication to enable its services and connects to the CIDR through their ASA/KSA /AUA/KUA.